# Using matplotlib on top of opencv image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am having some difficulty combining matplotlib and opencv. I have the following code that shows a video stream and pauses when the space bar is hit. I then want to use matplotlib to draw some annotations on top of the paused image (The user can then hit space to unpause and repeat the process). However, whenever I add any matplotlib functions it opens a separate figure window and I would ideally like to have my annotations directly on the image. I also looked at the available drawing functions in opencv and there is not enough functionality there for me (I am looking to fit a complicated curve to the paused image).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, im = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    im_g = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray,(5,5),0)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_g, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imshow('Window',im)  

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k > 0:
        print k
    if k == 32:
        ##########
        # Plot on top of image using matplotlib
        ##########
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        continue
    elif k == 27:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you put in some of matplotlib commands you want to use?  Also does matplotlib imshow as opposed to cv2 imshow work?

Comment: My Python experience is limited, but if I understand it right, this is happening in the C underneath and so I would expect that drawing on the same window would be very difficult. However, drawing the image in Matplotlib is not difficult at all; would it be possible to use Matplotlib for all of the drawing? You are even using greyscale, so the RGB/BGR won't be an issue.